# Reading XML using XDocument & Linq - check if element is NULL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

I'm using LINQ together with XDocument to read a XML File. This is the code:

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(filename);

var q = from b in xml.Descendants("product")
        select new
        {
            name = b.Element("name").Value,
            price = b.Element("price").Value,                    
            extra = b.Element("extra1").Value,
            deeplink = b.Element("deepLink").Value                   
        };
```

Now the problem is, the `extra1` field is not always present. There are items in the XML file without that node. If that happens it's crashing with a NullReferenceException.

Is there any possibility to include a "check if null" so I can prevent it from crashing?

Answer (score 43):

Use `(string)` instead of `.Value`:

```
var q = from b in xml.Descendants("product")
        select new
        {
            name = (string)b.Element("name"),
            price = (double?)b.Element("price"),                    
            extra = (string)b.Element("extra1"),
            deeplink = (string)b.Element("deepLink")                   
        };
```

This also works with [other datatypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.op_explicit.aspx), including many nullable types in case the element is not always present.

Answer (score 9):

You can use "null coalescing" operator:

```
var q = from b in xml.Descendants("product")
        select new
        {
            name = (string)b.Element("name") ?? "Default Name",
            price = (double?)b.Element("price") ?? 0.0,                    
            extra = (string)b.Element("extra1") ?? String.Empty,
            deeplink = (string)b.Element("deepLink") ?? String.Empty                   
        };
```

This way, you will have full control about default value used when there's no element.

Comment: `price` needs to be `double?` for that line to make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following example for checking existence of any element before using that element.

```cs
if( b.Elements("extra1").Any() )
{
   extra = b.Element("extra1").Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample example to read XML file using XDocument.

```
  XDocument objBooksXML = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("books.xml"));
    var objBooks = from book in
                   objBooksXML.Descendants("Book")
                   select new { 
                                Title = book.Element("Title").Value, 
                                Pages = book.Element("Pages").Value 
                              };

    Response.Write(String.Format("Total {0} books.", objBooks.Count()));
    gvBooks.DataSource = objBooks;
    gvBooks.DataBind();
```

Comment: The problem with this code is that if "Book" doesn't contain a "Title" or "Pages" element you'll throw a null exception when trying to get .Value from either of them.