# Read values from XDocument

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, asp.net-4.5

I need to enumerate an XML (XDocument) document as such...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<applied>
  <ah ID="8298" userId="87459" roleId="2700" />
  <ah ID="8300" userId="87459" roleId="2699" />
  <ah ID="8299" userId="87460" roleId="2700" />
</applied>
```

...and extract all the values of `userID` and `roleID` into two separate `StringBuilder` objects.

I've been messing about with Linq for the first time, but am struggling, and would appreciate some help please (this is a VB webforms app).  I have seen lots of Linq example that get a single value, but not two at the same time in the manner I need.

Also, this XML file could be up to 100,000 rows in length.  Is Linq more memory efficient than, say, a `FOR EACH` loop?  If not, could someone please provide a `FOR EACH` example?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:  The result would be:**

```
Userids = "87459,87459,87460"
roleIds = "2700,2699,2700"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to get the xml from your file system into memory. This is called deserialization. My preferred method of doing this is using a model for the xml, which is just a class with some attributes to tell the xml serializer how to parse the file:

```
<XmlRoot("applied")> _
Public Class Applied
    <XmlElement("ah")> _
    Public Property AhList As List(Of Ah)
End Class

Public Class Ah
    <XmlAttribute("ID")> _
    Public Property ID As Integer
    <XmlAttribute("userID")> _
    Public Property UserID As Integer
    <XmlAttribute("roleID")> _
    Public Property RoleID As Integer
End Class
```

Note that the XmlAttribute tells the serializer exactly what the attribute is called in xml, but you may use any name for it in the model, i.e. `<XmlAttribute("userID")> Public Property UserID As Integer`.

Now that you have this model, you need to deserialize from xml.

```
Dim appls As New Applied()
Dim serializer As XmlSerializer = Nothing
serializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(Applied))
appl = serializer.Deserialize(xd.CreateReader()) ' xd is your XDocument
```

Now you should have all the xml deserialized into the `appls` object. This object has a property, according to the model, called `AhList`, which is a list of all the elements in your xml. Since List(Of Ah) is IEnumerable, you can use LINQ on it.

Comment: Hi, thanks.  The `XDocument` object is already in memory, as it was returned from a function as `XDocument` not a string.  Can a `For Loop` be applied directly therefore without converting it to your custom class?  And, will Linq work without the class conversion?  Thank you.

Comment: The class just gives you a schema so you can strongly type the xml. You can refer to this Q&A on SO which shows how to LINQ to XDocument: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594582/reading-xml-using-xdocument-linq-check-if-element-is-null . Personally I prefer strong typing over accessing XML properties by string name, but both work.

Comment: Okay that's useful thanks.  Could you please amend your answer so that `Using sr As New StreamReader("xml file path here")` references an XDocument object already in memory?

Comment: I amended it, according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901558/how-do-i-deserialize-xml-into-an-object-using-a-constructor-that-takes-an-xdocum