# How to Read and Write to an XML file using XDocument and XElements?

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to write a simple List Manager application but I am running into issues Reading from and Writing to an XML document using XDocument and XElements.

```
public ListManager()
{
    AppSettingsReader asr = new AppSettingsReader();
    string listFile = (string)asr.GetValue("listFile", typeof(string));
    if (File.Exists(listFile))
    {
        listManager = XDocument.Load(listFile);
        items = (from e in listManager.Root.Elements() select new ListItem(e)).ToList();

        //listManager = XDocument.Load(listFile);
        //foreach (var item in listFile)
        //{
        //    if (item is XText)
        //    {
        //        listManager.Root.Elements()
        //    }
        //}
    }
    else
    {
        listManager = new XDocument();
        listManager.Add(new XElement("listManagerItems"));
        items = new List<ListItem>();
    }

    //listManager.Save(listFile);
}
```

App.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
   <appSettings>
     <add key="listFile" value="Data\listManagerItems.xml"/>
   </appSettings>
  <startup>
   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
 </configuration>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Root lev="0">
  <listitem></listitem>
  <dateMade></dateMade>
  <MM-dd-yyyy></MM-dd-yyyy>
  <itemdescription></itemdescription>
 </Root>
```

I am not really sure what is wrong since it seems to be functioning properly other than the read and write.

Comment: It is very hard to know what kind of problems you are facing by reading just "functioning properly other than the read and write". Please read similar answers (including linked as [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594582/reading-xml-using-xdocument-linq-check-if-element-is-null) or just https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%20read%20xml%20xdocument) and provide clear [MCVE] with clear explanation of problem you are facing (at very least exception message). You can [edit] this question - it will go to in re-open queue and if enough concrete details are the it may be reopen.